# didn't use to vs are not used to?

Tags: tense

Can I use this both forms interchangeably:

> 1. People who **didn't use** to (such abbreviations)...
> 2. People who **are not used** to (such abbreviations)...

I don't really feel /see the difference between these forms. For me the first sentence would be more natural, but in the text I was reading, the second form was used and it drew my attention.

What would be the difference between them?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first example in ungrammatical English. See **[this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/30137/192771)** at our sister site ELU.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, ok thanks, but this post doesn't actually answer my question. I'm not asking about the difference between didn't use to vs didn't used to.

Comment: I left this out of my explanation; there are actually ***three forms***: to be  used to [doing something]; I used to [do something], a defective form; and to use. People who didn't use to tell lies, shouldn't start now. So,  your 1) is OK but is not the same ***form*** as two.

Comment: @Lambie His 1st is wrong since there isn't a verb after **didn't use to**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is "**be used to***".

> If you **are used to something**, you are accustomed to it – you don’t find it unusual. If you **get used to something** or you **are getting used to something** you are becoming accustomed to it – it was strange, now it’s not so strange. ([**LearnEnglish - British Council**](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/used-infinitive-and-beget-used))
>
> Both ‘**be used to**’ and ‘**get used to**’ are followed by a **noun** *(or pronoun)* or the **gerund** – the ‘**ing**’ form of a **verb**

This concerns your second example, which is **correct** and **appropriate**:

- People who **are not used to** such abbreviations. (**Correct**)

The first sentence is **incorrect grammatically** since "didn't use to" is applied incorrectly in the sentence.

> We use ‘**used to**’ to talk about things that happened in the past – actions or states – that no longer happen now.
>
> The negative is ‘**didn’t use to**’ and questions are formed with ‘**Did you use to …?**’

- People who **didn't use to** such abbreviations. (**Incorrect**)
- People who **didn't use to understand** such abbreviations. (**Correct**)

Comment: The negative form of "used to" is contentious. So citation is needed for the latter part. Following Garner, I would say it should [didn't used to](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100674/didnt-use-to-get-or-didnt-used-to-get/100682#100682).

Comment: @user178049 **Didn't used to** is incorrect, the **didn't use to** is simply the past negative of the past **used to**.

Comment: I didn't say it was correct, and I didn't say it was wrong either. I'm just prompting you to add a citation because this issue is contentious and opinions may vary.

Comment: @user178049 Btw, I can't see why you say that the negative form of **used to** is contentious!

Comment: At first, I, too, thought it should be "didn't use to." But after reading this [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/100674/35026), I'm dubious. As Javalatte said, 'opinions vary'.

Comment: Yeh, that's familiar. However, you can't say "**didn't went to**" or "**didn't thought of**" and not even "**didn't had to**" so how come "**didn't used to**" is correct? People who speak that way either don't know grammar or are intentionally spoiling your language. We've got as many problems in Russian.

Comment: Of course it can be correct! :) Rules are sets of 'generalizations' and they can't blanket everything; that is, they'll always be an exception to every rule. Garner's argument (in Javalatte's answer) makes sense to me. Idioms like "used to" shouldn't follow conventional grammar.

Comment: @user178049 Yes, I am well aware of it. Notice that "**didn't used to**" is less comfortable to speak than "**didn't use to**"

Comment: I don't think so. My ears may not be perfect; I don't speak fluent English either. But I think "didn't used to" and "didn't use to" are virtually homophonous.

Answer (score 3):

The idiom is: **to be used to something**.

Present: People who aren't used [or are not used to] to wearing green [etc.]

Simple Past: People who were weren't [or were not used] to wearing green [etc.]

PP: People who haven't been used to [or have not been used to] wearing green [etc.]

Often, English language learners confuse **to be used to something** with **the verb to use** something and the defective imperfect form: I used to [do something].

The form **didn't use** is the **simple past tense of the verb use** and is not related to the  idiom given at the beginning of this answer. The verb use works like this in the SP:

He didn't use the paper I left on top of the printer.

The form of I used to [do something].
**I used to play tennis**=defective imperfect tense.
**Negative***: I didn't use to  play tennis, the negative is not so common.

For repeat actions in the past.

Comment: There is the negative form "**didn't use to**" of "**used to**" *(past actions and states)*. Consider: "**He didn't use to play with her a lot when they were kids**"

Comment: @SovereignSun One cannot cover every single thing under the sun. I was not commenting on "personal pronoun + used to". As in: I used to play football. That is another thing. And not the confusion of the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Just to sum up:

I mixed not 2 but actually 3 different forms up:

FIRST:

> 1. regular verb **use**
>
> 1.1. He used the paper I left on top of the printer.
>
> 1.2. NEG: He **didn't use** the paper I left on top of the printer.

SECOND:

> 2. idiomatic expression **be/ get used to**
>
> 2.1. People who are used to such abbreviations
>
> 2.2. NEG: People who **are not used** to such abbreviations.

and THIRD the most confusing:

> 3. defective verb **used to**
>
> 3.1. I used to smoke, but now I've stopped.
>
> NEG:
>
> 3.2. I **used to not like** opera, but now I do.
>
> 3.3. I **didn't use to like** opera, but now I do./ I **didn't use to drive** a big car.
>
> 3.4. I **use(d)n't  to like** opera, but now I do.

My example was:

> 4.1. People who didn't use **to** such abbreviations

not

> 4.2. People who didn't use such abbreviations. (AS: He didn't use the paper I left on top of the printer.)

and I wanted to use the sentence 4.1 with the meaning 3.3 but as I was pointed out it was incorrect. Now I understand why :)

Comment: You're welcome, however, please delete your answer as it isn't an answer or edit it so that it becomes an answer of your own.

Comment: @SovereignSun There's nothing wrong with an author writing an answer to their own question to explain what they know in their own words. I think explaining it from a different perspective is valuable. It should be written as an answer though, and not as part of a conversation. I've fixed it up a little bit for you Marcel. Feel free to change my edits.