# Can we say *I didn't use to like it when a friend used to visit without calling me first*?

Tags: phrase-usage

Can we say ***'I didn't use to like it when a friend used to visit without calling me first'*** to talk about something that happened often in the past and the speaker didn't use to like it?

> When I was at university **I didn't use to like it when my friends used to talk** loudly to each other during a movie but now I don't mind.

Is it a correct sentence?

Or are there any other ways of saying it?

Comment: I think either **I didn't use to like it when my friends talked** or **I didn't like it when my friends used to talk** would be preferable to saying **use** twice.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentences are correct, although opinions vary about whether you should write **didn't use to** or **didn't used to**. See [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100674/didnt-use-to-get-or-didnt-used-to-get) for more information, and for a recommendation to avoid this form if possible. One way to do this is to use the more formal **used not to**.

In your sentence, it is also possible to eliminate the problem by using simple past for the main clause, and using the modal verb in the subordinate clause to indicate habit.

> When I was at university, I didn't like it when my friends used to talk loudly to each other during a movie, but now I don't mind.

You could also do it the other way round, with **used to** only in the main clause, but then you don't eliminate that tricky **didn't used to**.

Comment: But the negative is 'I didn't use to.... ' right?  'When I was a child I didn't use to like tomatoes.' (the example is from Essential English Grammar by Raymond Murphy) Could you please explain "your sentences are correct, apart from the spelling of the modal verb, which should be used to."? I think in my question I used 'used to'. And the positive is 'I used to...' I used to read a lot of books but I don't read much these days.'

Comment: You are correct - see [here](https://grammar.cl/rules/used-to-use-to.htm#:~:text=Used%20to%20%3D%20an%20action%20or%20habit%20that,London%), though not all native speakers are aware of this. _Use to_ in the sense of _be in the habit of_ is now only used in the past tense.

Comment: Opinions vary about this: i have edited my question and  provided a link to a question specifically about **didn't use to** versus **didn't used to**.

Comment: In **Practical English Usage by Michael Swan** I found this: _When questions and negatives are written, they often have **did...used** instead of **did...use.** Many people consider this incorrect._     _1. What did people use(d) to do in the evenings before TV?_  _2. I didn't use(d) to like opera, but now I do._

Comment: May I suggest that we stick to comments specifically about the OP's question here? If you have further comments about whether it should be **didn't used to** or **didn't use to** or **used not to**, please direct them to the question specifically about that issue. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100674/didnt-use-to-get-or-didnt-used-to-get